# In Flutter, Is there a way to make the Scrollbar widget's width smaller than the child that is passed to it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, scrollbar

- I want my horizontal scrollable widgets to be able to go "off the screen" (disappearing at the screen edge).
- I also want the Scrollbar to not touch the screen edge.

I can currently only accomplish the first of these tasks. The scrollable red squares are a child of the Scrollbar, If padding is added, it will add padding to both the scrollable red squares & scroll bar.

```
      Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      controller: scrollController,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: scrollController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so that the scroll does not touch the edge of the screen, you must wrap the widget in charge of the scroll in a padding and that problem should already be solved, I leave it as an answer since my reputation does not allow me to add comments

Comment: If the Scrollbar or the scroll bars parent are given padding, then the scrollbar's child receives the same padding. This suggestion accomplishes my second bullet point, but then the first bullet is left unfinished.

Comment: please leave your code in the question to better understand your problem

Comment: added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure what you exactly mean but did some change one your code using [this question page and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286889/17356177)

this code uses a Elevated button to navigate (with animation) your scrollbar from bottom to top, sorry can't add a Gif right now :_)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation<Offset> offset;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));

    offset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, 1.0))
        .animate(controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scrollController = ScrollController();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Show / Hide'),
                onPressed: () {
                  switch (controller.status) {
                    case AnimationStatus.completed:
                      controller.reverse();
                      break;
                    case AnimationStatus.dismissed:
                      controller.forward();
                      break;
                    default:
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SlideTransition(
                position: offset,
                child: Scrollbar(
                  thumbVisibility: true,
                  controller: scrollController = ScrollController(),
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                            SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                                color: Colors.red,
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated to share a code snippet. Could you manipulate the code snippet to do what you are talking about?

Comment: I am happy to clarify my question. My concern does relate to a button or disappearing content or the animation itself. It only has to do with padding/margin/width of the scrollbar widget and the padding/margin/width of the scrollbar's child.

This might be simpler.
I am trying to think of a way to add horizontal padding to the scroll bar without adding that same padding to the scrollbar's child widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RawScrollbar` instead of `Scrollbar`.

You will get more customization options with the `RawScrollbar`.

To give padding to the Scrollbar so it doesn't touch the screen edge, you can use the *`mainAxisMargin`* of the `RawScrollbar`.

```
RawScrollbar(
  mainAxisMargin: 10,
  child: ListView(),
),
```