# showDialog from root widget

Tags: flutter

I want to show a dialog from root widget (the one that created MaterialApp) I have a `NavigatorState` instance, but showDialog requires context that would return `Navigator.of(context)`.

It looks like I need to provide context from a route, but I can't do this, because the root widget does not have it.

EDIT: I have found a workaround: I can push fake route that is only there to showDialog and then pop that route when dialog finishes. Not pretty but works.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using `navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context`. Here is example:

```
class GlobalDialogApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GlobalDialogAppState createState() => _GlobalDialogAppState();
}

class _GlobalDialogAppState extends State<GlobalDialogApp> {
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  void show() {
    final context = navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context;
    final dialog = AlertDialog(
      content: Text('Test'),
    );
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (x) => dialog);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Show alert'),
            onPressed: show,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @stuckedoverflow I looked at source code of Navigator and found out that it contains Overlay widget.

Comment: thanks, `navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context;` did the trick.

Comment: It no longer works as of Flutter version 1.7.X, I've posted a working solution that's more consistent.

Comment: @OliverDixon still works for me. Also, you seem to have very old version of flutter, 1.7.8 was released one year ago.

Comment: @szotp flutter version 1.7.0 was release a few months ago. They have inconsistent version numbers. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

Comment: @OliverDixon according to your link, 1.7.0 was released on 3.06.2019

Comment: @szotp X means any new sub-version. So 1.0.X could be 1.0.1 or 1.0.9. The link states: 1.17.5, 8af6b2f, 02/07/2020 << recent.

Comment: @OliverDixon So you meant 1.17.X, not 1.7.X?

Comment: @szotp those dam version numbers

Comment: @OliverDixon anyway, my solution still works in 1.20, can you describe what issue you had?

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr:** If you want to call `showDialog` from your root widget, extrude your code into another widget (e.g. a `StatelessWidget`), and call `showDialog` there.

Anyway, in the following I'm going to assume you are running into this issue:

```
flutter: No MaterialLocalizations found. 
flutter: MyApp widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor. 
flutter: Localizations are used to generate many different messages, labels,and abbreviations which are used by the material library.
```

As said before, [showDialog](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showDialog.html) can only be called in a [BuildContext](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) whose ancestor has a [MaterialApp](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html). Therefore you **can't** directly call `showDialog`if you have a structure like this:

```
- MaterialApp
  - Scaffold
    - Button // call show Dialog here
```

In a code example this would result in code like this, **throwing** the error given above:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Show dialog!'),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Dialog(
                        child: Text('Dialog.'),
                      );
                    });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To solve this error from occuring you can create a new `Widget`, which has its own `BuildContext`. The modified structure would look like this:

```
- MaterialApp
  - Home

- Home     // your own (Stateless)Widget
  - Button // call show Dialog here
```

Modifying the code example to the structure given above, results in the code snippet below. `showDialog`can be called **without** throwing the error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Home()
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Show dialog!'),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Dialog(
                      child: Text('Dialog.'),
                    );
                  });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Obviously this will work, but my use case is for example showing alert when notifications comes in. It can happen in any state of the app, therefore I don't have specific page to show the dialog in. Maybe if there was one page that is always in hierarchy it could work, but that's not the case for my app currently.

Comment: @krzat Oh sorry, maybe you wanna try using the [Overlay](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) widget instead. If you have a `NavigatorState`, there shouldn't be a problem with displaying it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219599/flutter-notify-from-top-of-the-screen/53230359#53230359)). To create the same effect as with the `showDialog` function, you can make it full screen size and give it a background-color with opacity.

Comment: Maybe `navigator.overlay.context` will do the trick, I will check that.

Comment: @Niklas Why does your first example throws the exception? The Exception message reads `To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a  MaterialApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, or ....` which you have done in your first example. Can you please explain why your Second example works and not the first?

Comment: The first `buildContext` is not a child of the `MaterialApp`.  By moving the code to a different child widget of the `MaterialApp` (in this case `Home`) we update the `buildContext`.

Comment: Failed assertion: line 446 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true. getting this error when pass context to API calling method in a flutter.

Answer (score 2):

They changed the way the navigator overlay works.
This is the working solution for us as the accepted one isn't anymore.

```
// If you want to use the context for anything.
final context = navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context;
// How to insert the dialog into the display queue.
navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.insert(anyDialog);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a `context` object, you can get root material app's context by
`final rootContext = context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>().context`

and passing this to `showDialog` or `showModalBottomSheet` context argument.

Answer (score 1):

Since `showDialog` is used for showing a material dialog It can be used for showing dialogs inside a `MaterialApp` widget only. It can not be used to show dialog outside it.

Comment: I have a reference to `NavigatorState` so I don't see why it shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, inject the navigator key into a dialog widget like so.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key});

  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      // ...
      builder: (context, routeChild) {
        return Material(
          child: InviteRequestModal(
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
            child: routeChild,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Then in the Widget that requires the modal, you can use it as mentioned above.

```
class InviteRequestModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  InviteRequestModal({
    Key key,
    this.child,
    this.navigatorKey,
  }) : super(key: key);

  void _showInviteRequest(InviteRequest invite) {
    final context = navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context;

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        // Your dialog content
        return Container();
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<InviteContactsBloc, InviteContactsState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is InviteRequestLoaded,
      listener: (_, state) {
        if (state is InviteRequestLoaded) {
          _showInviteRequest(state.invite);
        }
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer just that simple, when you are providing MaterialApp to the tree it was providing but at the immediate bottom you are the context which obtained before providing MaterialApp to the tree. To resolve the issue you need to create a new context which will have the MaterialApp properties. For that wrap a Builder above the home and vola it is working...!

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return HomePage(
          child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => Dialog(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      height: 50,
                      width: 100,
                      child: Text("Hi, I am a dialog"),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text("Tap me"),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

For those wanting to see how to do this in a multiple widget/route/file scenario, I used it with `InheritedWidget` and an extension on `BuildContext`.

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app_navkey.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppNavKey(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        theme: ThemeData(),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: HomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`home_screen.dart`

```dart
import 'package:myapp/extensions.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final overlayContext = context.navigationKey().currentState.overlay.context;
    return Center(
      child: TextButton(
          child: Text('Show dialog!'),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: overlayContext, // use app level navigation context overlay
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Dialog(
                    child: Text('Dialog.'),
                  );
                });
          },
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

`app_navkey.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class AppNavKey extends InheritedWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  AppNavKey({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.navigatorKey,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> of(BuildContext context) {
    final ctx = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppNavKey>();
    if (ctx == null) throw Exception('Could not find ancestor of type AppNavProvider');
    return ctx.navigatorKey;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}
```

`extensions.dart`

````dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app_navkey.dart';

extension SwitchTabContext on BuildContext {
  /// Get app level NavigatorState key.
  /// ```dart
  /// context.navigationKey();
  /// ```
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey() => AppNavKey.of(this);
}
````