# showing a dialog doesn't work when the widget is the direct child of MaterialApp

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to create an alert dialog in Flutter, but the dialog doesn't work when it is under MaterialApp and instead gives an error. Below is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Inputs and alerts'),
        ),
        body: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('This is a text'),
                  content: Text('this is the content'),
                  actions: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                      },
                      child: Text('No'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                      },
                      child: Text('Yes'),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**
[image]

But when I extract the ElevatedButton to a stand-alone widget, the alert dialog works fine. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Inputs and alerts'),
        ),
        body: sn(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class sn extends StatelessWidget {
  const sn({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('This is a text'),
                content: Text('this is the content'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                    },
                    child: Text('No'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                    },
                    child: Text('Yes'),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Can anyone tell me the cause of this behaviour? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will give some insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294551/showdialog-from-root-widget

Comment: Okay! I got the solution. But I can't understand the reason that why is it happening? Can you please explain if you have any idea?

Comment: i don't know man,check this answer this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53296254/13418165

Comment: Thanks, bro. I didn't go through that answer before. It cleared a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you can only call `showDialog(context)` passing in a `BuildContext` that has an `MaterialApp` as an ancestor widget. The context you're getting access in your *build() method* from your first example is a **context** that does not have any `MaterialApp` above it.

Just like you did, you can solve this by extracting your `Scaffold` into another widget to have access to it's `BuildContext` in the build method.

Another solution is to use a `Builder` widget. It exposes a new context to it's child that now has in it the reference to any widget above it (in this case the `MaterialApp`).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Inputs and alerts'),
          ),
          body: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('This is a text'),
                    content: Text('this is the content'),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                        },
                        child: Text('No'),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                        },
                        child: Text('Yes'),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @dipansh no problem! Flutter has a video about Builder widget on youtube  if you wan't to know more. See ya.